# Is there a way to use Java Web Start with browsers that don't support?

Tags: java, deployment, java-web-start

Is there a way to use Java Web Start with browsers that don't support Java?
I know the JNLP file can run locally as long as it references the jar correctly, but then I have to make my users first get the JNLP file.

### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Dynamic Tree Java Web Start Application </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
  </head>
  <body>         
    <script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>   
    <h2>Java Web Start application deployed by using the <code>createWebStartLaunchButtonEx</code> function</h2>    
    <script>        
        var jnlpFile = "dynamictree_webstart.jnlp";
        deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButtonEx(jnlpFile);
    </script>
    <noscript>JavaScript is required for this page.</noscript>    
  </body>
</html>
```

### JNLP

```xml
<jnlp spec="1.0+" 
    href="dynamictree_webstart.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Dynamic Tree Demo</title>
        <vendor>Dynamic Team</vendor>
    </information>
      <security>
          <all-permissions/>
      </security>
    <update check="background"/>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="DynamicTreeDemo.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc
         main-class="webstartComponentArch.DynamicTreeApplication">
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to use Java Web Start with browsers that don't support Java?

Certainly. The only type of deployment blocked by browsers that *"don't support Java"* is that of an **embedded** applet. Launch the applet (or a frame) free floating from a link on a browser using JWS and the browser will not have any (responsibility for, or) control over the launch.

> ```
> deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButtonEx(jnlpFile);
> ```

This script will break in any browser that does not support the Java Plug-In, since it uses the browser plug-in for checking the Java version.

Comment: We're not using an applet.  With Chrome, I got the following messages: Download Java for Windows Recommended Version 8 Update 73.  This was followed by: We have detected you are using Google Chrome and might be unable to use the Java plugin from this browser. Starting with Version 42 (released April 2015), Chrome has disabled the standard way in which browsers support plugins. After upgrading Java, and retrying I got this: The Chrome browser does not support NPAPI plug-ins and therefore will not run all Java content. Switch to a different browser to run the Java plug-in

Comment: Show the JNLP, and the HTML used to launch the JNLP. You are apparently doing it wrong, but it is hard to tell exactly what is going wrong with so little detail on how it is being launched.

Comment: Not enough space here and I can't get it formatted correctly if I edit my original post.  Suggestions?

Comment: *"Not enough space here.."*  Don't give me that. I posted code that was just over 650 lines. If the combined JNLP/HTML/JS is longer than that, make a simplified example (test and check it fails) then..  *"see code at jsfiddle.."* No. Post it here. *"I can't get it formatted correctly if I edit my original post. Suggestions?"* Learn how to use code formatting on SO. Go through the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for tips.

Comment: 1) You do realize, right, that SO supports JS code? 2) By posting code 'here' I meant [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35482120/edit). 3) I'm not following an external link.

Comment: Updated original post.